# terminal showing as "no tests ran", even-though script worked correctly

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, pytest

```
import pytest
import openpyxl


class test_Read_From_Excel:
    workbook_object = openpyxl.load_workbook("/Users/kartik.tumu/Desktop/Testing Screen Shots/CBS/Selenium/Test Data.xlsx")
    print(workbook_object.sheetnames)

#object of sheet "sh"
    sh = workbook_object["TestData"]

#object of cell "c1" username
    c1 = sh.cell(6,4)

#object of cell "p1" password
    p1 = sh.cell(6,5)

    print(p1.value)
    print(c1.value)

    print('\n Testcase Passed','green')
    print("==================================================")
```

Hello All,
I am new to python and pytest , and I trying to automate my application using Selenium Webdriver with Pycharm IDE.

When I execute the above script it is working fine, but terminal showing as "no tests ran in 1.54s" & collected 0 items.

Please explain , what mistake I have done here. Try to give a detail explanation in layman's language.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple of things:

- pytest runs functions which start with the word `test`
- you need some assertions in order to have a test

So you could rewrite that as:

```
import openpyxl


def test_Read_From_Excel():
    workbook_object = openpyxl.load_workbook("/Users/kartik.tumu/Desktop/Testing Screen Shots/CBS/Selenium/Test Data.xlsx")
    print(workbook_object.sheetnames)

    #object of sheet "sh"
    sh = workbook_object["TestData"]

    #object of cell "c1" username
    c1 = sh.cell(6,4)

    #object of cell "p1" password
    p1 = sh.cell(6,5)

    print(p1.value)
    print(c1.value)

    assert c1.value == 42
```

I only added one assertion, you'd need to edit the test and put in the assertions you actually want. Tests should generally not have any print statements.